# Pound SSL Wrapper Wordpress Login Issue

Tags: nginx, ssl, wordpress, pound

my Setup is like this

Visitor -> Pound -> Varnish -> nginx

My Wordpress site is looking fine from the front end (with https), but as soon i try to login to the backend this error comes up "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page."

When i take Pound out of the chain it works fine (with Varnish only http) but nginx directly without varnish also with SSL.

This is my pound config

```
User            "www-data"
Group           "www-data"
LogLevel        1
Alive           30
Control "/var/run/pound/poundctl.socket"

ListenHTTP
    Address  0.0.0.0
    Port     80
    Service
        BackEnd
            Address 127.0.0.1
            Port    6081
        End
    End
End

ListenHTTPS
    HeadRemove "X-Forwarded-Proto"
    AddHeader  "X-Forwarded-Proto: https"
    Address    0.0.0.0
    Port       443
    Cert       "/etc/ssl/domain.com/mycert.pem"

    Service
        BackEnd
            Address 127.0.0.1
            Port    6081
        End
    End
End
```

Server is Ubuntu 14.04

thanks

Comment: Could you provide relevant parts of varnish configuration? the output of ``netstat -laputen`` when all bricks work together? can you launch ``tcpdump -elnXi lo port 6081`` when pound is working, and ``tcpdump -elnXi eth0 port 80``without it? As to compare both situations, to track credentials, with and without pound.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the error.
Its i forgot to add those lines to the wp-config.php

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
   $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```